# Android Emulator: Changing network bars

Tags: android, emulation, adt, telnet, ddms

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the visible network bars in the android emulator? I've searched google, tried with telnet and DDMS, but no luck.

Alternately, does anyone know where I can get png files of the bar images (in 2.3)? What I'm ultimately trying to do is get some screenshots of the different levels (1 bar, 2 bars, ect). I went down the route of trying to get the android source code, but it didn't go so well.

Comment: you need to learn a little photoshop :)

Comment: I am very familiar with photoshop, but if you examine the network bars they are not as simple as they first appear. There is a glow around them so that you cannot easily copy-paste and resize. Also, this feels a bit like cheating to me. I'd rather find an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for necroposting but I was searching for the same thing and while I failed to get an instant answer on SO I though I should post my finding here as it answers the initial question.
To set the network reception level in the emulator you need to connect to it using telnet

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

normally your emulator will be running on port 5554 but you can always check this in the title bar of your emulator window.
after that you can run the command

```
gsm signal NN
```

where NN is an int 0..31 indicating signal level. thus the command

```
gsm signal 0
```

will give you no bars. hope someone will find this useful some day. happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the status bar drawables from [here](http://androiddrawables.com/status.html)

Search for `stat_sys_signal_`. I didnot check the resolution of these. But if these are low res, you might have to download Android open source code. The drawables will be present at `frameworks\base\core\res\res\drawable-hdpi`

Answer (score 0):

in your ddms view emulator tab from eclipse, you can change the status and power of the network, battery ... Else, you have to telnet your emulator and send it commands

Comment: How? This is my emulator tab. [link](http://raydowe.com/static/emulator_tab.jpg) There are settings for voice and data, but nothing about signal strength. Nothing I choose seems to change the bars.

I'm not sure I believe it's possible through telnet. What would the command be?